# Lock aspect ratio on part of grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

I'm trying to write a function wherein our company logo is automatically added to each graph on export as part of a function, next to the title and subtitle. The dimensions of each output will depend on the needs at the time, so having a set size won't be particularly helpful unfortunately.

To do this, I've generated a series of grids to slot everything together, as per the below (using the iris dataset).

```
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(png)

m <- readPNG("Rlogo.png") # download from: https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png

plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_col() +
  ggtitle("Title goes here",
          subtitle = "subtitle down here")


txtTitle <- plot$labels$title
txtSubTitle <- plot$labels$subtitle

plot$labels$title <- NULL
plot$labels$subtitle <- NULL

buffer <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp = gpar(fill = "white", col = "white")))

Title <- grobTree(textGrob(label = txtTitle,  
                           hjust = 1, 
                           x = 0.98))
SubTitle <- textGrob(label = txtSubTitle, 
                     hjust = 1, 
                     x = 0.98)
Logo <- grobTree(rasterGrob(m, x = 0.02, hjust = 0))



TitlesGrid <- grid.arrange(Title, SubTitle, ncol = 1)
TopGrid <- grid.arrange(Logo, TitlesGrid, widths = c(1, 7), ncol = 2)
AllGrid <- grid.arrange(TopGrid, arrangeGrob(plot), heights = c(1,7))
```

This provides the following outputs at different aspect ratios.

[image: Good spacing]
[image: Bad Output]

The first example has a nice gap between the title and subtitle whereas there is too much for the second one. How would I make it so that the height of `TopGrid` is fixed to an absolute size, but the rest fills to the size desired?

Comment: I think that will require that you choose an output format that supports such an attribute specification, perhaps pdf? I doubt that it will be possible to do with png, jpeg, or tiff. Maybe you could create some sort of pseudo-device that might merge a fixed size graphic with `Something else`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grid graphics has the concept of absolute and relative units. Absolute units (such as "cm", "in", "pt") always stay the same size, regardless of the viewport size. Relative units (called "null") expand or shrink as needed. In a regular ggplot2 object, the plot panel is specified in relative units while the various elements around the panel, such as title, axis ticks, etc. are specified in absolute units.

You specify absolute or relative units with the `unit()` function:

```
> library(grid)
> unit(1, "cm")
[1] 1cm
> unit(1, "null")
[1] 1null
```

In your case, the `heights` argument of `grid.arrange` can take arbitrary grid unit objects, so you just have to give the top height an absolute unit:

```
grid.arrange(TopGrid, arrangeGrob(plot), heights = unit(c(1, 1), c("cm", "null")))
```

[image]

[image]